# How can I return list object to ajax call back function from asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, post, highcharts

I'm beginner in asp.net and write simple web application to show user any chart using highcharts tools, in highcharts need read data with ajax and for that purpose I write this code:

```
function FetchData() {
            var pData = [];
            pData[0] = $("#ddlyear").val();
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ pData: pData });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CS.aspx/GetDataBehzad",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess_,
                error: OnErrorCall_
            });
            function OnSuccess_(response) {
                var aData = response.d;
                alert(aData);
            }
            function OnErrorCall_(response) {
                alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

and in `CS.aspx` write this code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public List<int> GetDataBehzad()
        {

            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(10);
            list.Add(100);
            return list;

        }
```

But when I run the application I get OnErrorCall function alert from ajax, how can I solve that? What is problem? thanks every one.

Comment: why data is empty in your ajax post? And you sure it is a POST request? I think you are trying to fetch some data. It should be a GET reaquest

Comment: @Sharukhkshaji yes i want fetch some data,and change post to get,but so get error

Comment: Did you debug your code? Please check whether the onsuccess_() method is invoking or not. And check what is response.d. Then please list your error

Comment: Which platform you are working in asp .net mvc or asp.net web service?

Comment: @868k my plat form is asp.net 4 web form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Method "Static"

that is the only issue in your code

see below

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static List<int> GetDataBehzad()
{

    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(10);
    list.Add(100);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let see this is not and complete answer but a direction to a result. Try something like returning Json/Xml result from the action WebMethod. I have tried with mvc it is working on my site. You just need to see if  JsonResult/Similar something  is by default supported in webform or just find a class library.

```
    public JsonResult   GetDataBehzad()
    {

        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(10);
        list.Add(100); 
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute.

Your method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<int> GetDataBehzad()
    {

        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(10);
        list.Add(100);
        return list;
    }
```